# Inadvertently performed rm command inside the home folder: what are the worst consequences for the system as a whole if there is any?

Tags: centos

```
find . -type f -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

Fortunately I was able to restore the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` before I could even think about logging out. But I'm scared about other important things inside my `/home/user` directory particularly this `.config` directory that I never open. Is the whole system still safe? Other than of course all my files and backups that are there.

Comment: So far I can still log in. But I am still worried that there is a bomb waiting to explode anytime because of what I've done. I want to know what are these directories: .local, .config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the whole system still safe?

It should be unless you've granted your user access to system-wide directories.

> I want to know what are these directories: .local, .config.

Directories and files starting with dot in `/home/$user` contain configuration files for various applications. Nothing will happen if you delete them accidentally except some application will forget their settings.

More info:

https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

[Hidden Files&Directories in user's home directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119792/hidden-filesdirectories-in-users-home-directory)

https://www.maketecheasier.com/hidden-files-linux-home-directory/

https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Important_hidden_.dot_files_in_your_home_partition

Firefox and Thunderbird store their profiles in ~/.mozilla and ~/.thunderbird respectively so if you use them you could have lost some profile data, including history, cookies, passwords, etc. etc. etc.